# Loading data from network for a TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, rest

In my app, I have a ViewController that obtains data from the user, then segue to a TableViewController. My TableViewController displays data acquired from a REST call to a remote server.

I have coded the http request in the ViewDidLoad, and when the data is received, I then call

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

But it takes forever (5-10 sec.) for the data to appear in the TableView, after the REST call completes.

Should I place my REST call elsewhere? For instance, would it be better to do all the data retrieval in the initial ViewController, then segue when all the data is ready?

I don't think my code is all that relevant, but here is the code inside my ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    DataManager.spSearch { (teamsJson) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: teamsJson)
        //println(json)

        if let teamArray = json["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"].array {
            for teamDict in teamArray {
                //println(teamDict)
                if let teamCells = teamDict["Cells"]["results"].array {
                    var teamTitle: String = ""
                    var teamUrl: String = ""
                    for teamCell in teamCells {
                        // Each cell contains the value of a specific managed metadata
                        // validate if we are on the right one
                        if teamCell["Key"].string == "Title" {
                            println("Title=" + teamCell["Value"].string!)
                            teamTitle = teamCell["Value"].string!
                        }
                        if teamCell["Key"].string == "SPWebUrl" {
                            println("SPWebUrl=" + teamCell["Value"].string!)
                            teamUrl = teamCell["Value"].string!
                            let tenantLength = count(globalTenant)
                            // Remove the string containing the tenant frmo the beginning
                            teamUrl = suffix(teamUrl, count(teamUrl) - count(globalTenant))
                        }
                    }

                    var team = Team(name: teamTitle, url: teamUrl)
                    self.teams.append(team)
                }
            }
            println("Nb of teams= \(self.teams.count)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code looks OK. I think you are doing something else wrong and that actually takes 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you call `reloadData` on the background thread. Try this:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Would you care to explain why running this inside the main queue makes it instantaneous, as opposed to the background thread? I added a network indicator busy inside my DataManager code (`UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true`), and it shows that it takes 1-2 sec to get the data. Without your code, it then takes another 5-10 sec. to display in the tableview, but your code makes it seamless.

Comment: @pierrebo Of course. The DataManager blocks are executed on a background thread. When you update your UI you should do that on the main thread. Otherwise you could see strange delays like this.